# How can I orderBy a component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am rendering a component that display an array and I want them to be order by the last entry.

I've tried to do a function outside the render that orderBy and include it in the component but it's not mounting correctly.

```
orderBy() {
        let data = this.state;
        data.data.sort((a, b) => {
return a.published_on - b.published_on
}).map((data) => {
return data;
})
    }

render() {
        const { loading, data } = this.state;

        return (
            <div className="list">
                <Table rowKey="ref" loading={loading} dataSource={data.data} size="large" />
            </div>
        );
    }
```

I want the Table component to be order on the loading by data.data.published_on.

What is the correct way to do that in React ?

Comment: _"I've tried to do a function outside the render that orderBy"_: you should add that to your question.

Comment: @Andy I've added the function

Comment: And how are you calling `orderBy`?

Comment: that where I have a problem when I call it in Table the page doesn't mount

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You're not returning anything from the function.

2) Since you're using class components you'll need to call it with `this.orderBy`

3) Instead of grabbing `data` from the state pass it into the function instead:

```
orderBy(data) {
  return data.sort((a, b) => a.published_on - b.published_on);
}

render() {
  const { loading, data } = this.state;

  return (
    <div className="list">
      <Table rowKey="ref" loading={loading} dataSource={this.orderBy(data.data)} size="large" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: That dit the trick, just needed to declare data as an array in the orderBy function and it worked